# Deciding when a platform should have its own site

Tags: discussion, area-51

I just bought a [Chromebook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromebook) and so have lots of questions.

Presumably Stack Overflow is the natural place to ask these, but since most of them relate to the specific hardware and OS/browser combination it seems just as valid to have its own site as does [Raspberry Pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi).

Other than community size/interest, is there any rule for when a topic should have its own site?

Comment: In my eyes: Programming questions go to SO, user settings/general usage/how tos are off topic, and if there are enough of them (say about a hundred a day), they can get their own site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And why wouldn't https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/chromebook be the right place?

Unless you have a programming question it's going to be completely off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Having only 28 questions on SU seems like a good indication it's not going to be able to sustain a new site.

Comment: Why would you need a new site? It's a valid topic for Super User. Not _everything_ needs a Stack Exchange site. Too narrow is just as bad as too broad.

Comment: But SO is for programming topics. "How do I do X on machine Y/in Application Z?" would seem to be off topic

Comment: @MartinBeckett: Yes, but that's absolutely on topic at [su].

Comment: Good point - I had always thought of SU as "when you don't own the computer" ie. for servers

Comment: @Martin: That'd be [sf].

Comment: @AlEverett - in the immortal words of Homer Simpson - d'oh